# How to nest a tibble

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
players<-data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          seat = c("Seat 1","Seat 2","Seat 3",
                   "Seat 4","Seat 5","Seat 6"),
       jugador = c("MSC1266","Cereghetti16",
                   "Trytopredict","klariti","P.H.F.17","FerzRu"),
         stack = c("1.90 ", "2.03 ", "2 ", "2.60 ", "1.52 ", "3.99 "),
      posicion = c("BU", "SB", "BB", "EP", "MP", "CO"),
          hand = c("218755078355","218755078355",
                   "218755078355","218755078355","218755078355",
                   "218755078355")
```

)

And I would like to nest it based in "hand" column, in order to have one row, with all the values of the column in one vector. But when i do that:

```
jugadores %>% nest(hand)

 # A tibble: 6 x 5
   seat   jugador      stack   posicion data            
   <chr>  <chr>        <chr>   <chr>    <list>          
 1 Seat 1 MSC1266      "1.90 " BU       <tibble [1 x 1]>
 2 Seat 2 Cereghetti16 "2.03 " SB       <tibble [1 x 1]>
 3 Seat 3 Trytopredict "2 "    BB       <tibble [1 x 1]>
 4 Seat 4 klariti      "2.60 " EP       <tibble [1 x 1]>
 5 Seat 5 P.H.F.17     "1.52 " MP       <tibble [1 x 1]>
 6 Seat 6 FerzRu       "3.99 " CO       <tibble [1 x 1]>
 Warning message:
 All elements of `...` must be named.
 Did you want `data = c(hand)`?
```

Comment: `jugadores %>% nest(-hand)`

Answer (score 0):

```
players %>% 
  group_by(hand) %>% 
  nest()
```

or

```
players %>% 
  group_nest(hand)
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27274809).